# how to associate child node to its parent node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

i make a jtree which take value from user[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0a88.png)

i want whenever i add a child Node it return its parent node.
i have written the following code.

```
   if(selectednode != null)
    {             
          if( selectednode.getParent() != null && selectednode.isLeaf() )
         {       
             System.out.println("ppaarreenntt : "+ selectednode);            
         }
```

but the problem with this code when i add a child node instead of returning the parent node it returns its grandparent node

Comment: Most probably the problem is that when you add a child node you execute that piece of code before changing selectednode to the new child node and it is basically the previous node and in this case it does what you are seeing. If you want more help you would need to provide more code. For example where is selectednode initialized and where do you change it to the new node

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: my logic in the above code is that when you select a particular node then write child node in Jtextfield click add button. then the above code run, selectednode is already parent node so its return its parent rather then returning the newly selected node parent .
@VeselinDavidov , yes you are right. i am unable to understand how can i do it.